with all my effort
I was doing a gap-filling exercise and wrote a sentence that went like this:

Had I known she was in trouble, I would have helped her with all my effort.

But then I started wondering if there is such a collocation as ... with all my effort.
Is the sentence I made up a natural and idiomatic one? I looked up the word 'effort' in the dictionary and found that there are phrases like 'to make an effort to', 'to make every effort to', or 'to do something with effort'. So what do native speakers think about the one I wrote? Is it good? Could it be improved in any way?

It doesn't feel idiomatic to me. This Ngram shows that it has always been uncommon until a sudden spike around 2020. It isn't 'wrong', but something like "I would have done all I could to help her" sounds more natural.

I agree with Kate that it is grammatical but it sounds like a translation, not something from the mouth of a native speaker.  However, the structure of your prepositional phrase, with all my effort, can be used. For example, "In the tug-of-war game, I pulled with all my might".   That means I pulled using all my strength; I did not pull  only half-heartedly.  You could also say "I would have helped in any way I could."

@KateBunting Drawing conclusions from nGrams can be tricky. The steepness of the spike might just be the result of amplifying a small data set. When we add in "with all my strength", the increase in "with all my effort" looks more modest.

While it might not be common, it's easily understood and I don't see any actual problem with it. If we never used uncommon phrases, the language would be stuck.

This sentence is more idiomatic:
Had I known she was in trouble, I would have put all my efforts to help her.

It's not clear where the gap was and how many words could fill that gap. Was it a transformation sentence for a level B2 exam? Please clarify what the task was and if the term "effort" was included in the original sentence.

@Mari-LouA The “Had I known” part was given, and the student can write whatever they prefer for the rest. It has nothing to do with the word ‘effort’ I guess, I myself caused the problem.

So it wasn't a gap fill question, it was a "complete the sentence" task. My take: Had I known she was in trouble, I would have done things differently.  Kate's  "I would have done all I could to help her" and Lambie's "every effort to help [her]“ are good answers

Sample: Had I known she was in trouble, I would have helped her with all my effort.
Idiom:
to make every effort to [help someone]

Had I known she was in trouble, I would have made every effort to help her.

would have made every effort to help her. is more idiomatic...

Thanks Lambie. There’s an adverb-like phrase: all out, would it be good to say: I would have gone all out to help her had I known she was in trouble? Also, does the wording ‘had I known that’ sound old-fashioned or formal at all?

@Angyang Sure, to go all out to help someone. Same idea. No, we say: Had I known x all the time. Why would you think it is old fashioned?
